# Having trouble with Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to implement a Prolog task in order to learn it:

1. num_cred(X,Y): this function should take a list of course
   abbreviations as input (X), and output the number of credits
   obtained when a student attended these courses (Y).
2. courses(X,Y): this function should take a student as input (X), and
   output a list of all courses this student attended (Y).
3. pass2(X): this function should take a student as input, and output
   true if the student has 30 or more ECTS based on num_cred(X).
4. fail2(X): this function should take a student as input, and output
   true if the student has less than 30 ECTS based on num_cred(X).

Terminal input-output pairs examples:

```
Input                       Output

num_cred([pai,qf,d],X).     30

courses(alice,X).           [pai,qf,d]

pass2(X).                   alice

fail2(X).                   bob
```

This is what I've done until now:

```
num_cred([], 0).
num_cred([H|T], Sum) :- num_cred(T, Rest), course(H, P, C), Sum is C + Rest.
courses(X,Y).
pass2(X).
fail2(X).

/*Level 2 tests*/

course(pai,inf,10).
course(qf,eco,10).
course(d,law,10).

student(alice,ss).
attend(alice,pai).
attend(alice,qf).
attend(alice,d).

student(bob,ss).
attend(bob,pai).
```

Do you have any idea why my num_cred rule don't work? When I test it with num_cred([qf,pai],0). I get: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated.

Any help/ hints with these rules will be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What happens if you query `num_cred([qf, pai], X).`? It's unclear why you queried, `num_cred([qf, pai], 0).`. Why would you ask if the total credits for those two courses is 0? Not to mention, neither query yields an error that arguments are not sufficiently instantiated. So you either didn't run that query or the code you're showing isn't what you tested.

Comment: >What happens if you query num_cred([qf, pai], X).?  >> Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

Comment: That's not what I get when I run the code you show in your question. Please recheck what it is you're doing. By the way, `pass2(X).` and `fail2(X).` succeed for any value of X. They are meaningless.

Comment: @Simeon: This works fine in SWI prolog. Which one are you using?

Comment: Swi prolog as well...

Comment: Every time I asked a question on stack overflow I do not get any relevant answer. People here just downvote questions for fun. Although the question asked is clear, a lot of people use the comments just to ask irrelevant questions. I know I will get hate for this, but I think that stackoverflow is not relevant at all.

Comment: Some people here are less helpful than others, that is true. But even the helpful ones cannot help if they cannot reproduce your problem. Are you sure that the code you posted is the exact code you are running? What version of SWI are you using? On what operating system? Could you run the query `?- trace, num_cred([qf, pai], 0).`, keep pressing Enter until you either get `false` or `ERROR`, and paste the entire output into your question?

Comment: *Every time I asked a question on stack overflow I do not get any relevant answer. People here just downvote questions for fun.*. I think there are some hasty downvoters here, for sure. In this case, I loaded your code without any changes into SWI Prolog and did not get the errors running the queries you say you ran. So you need to examine what you're doing carefully before posting. You can waste a lot of peoples' time if you are being sloppy with what code goes with what results. You might also see warnings you should address.